# Automatically load & save folds of files - except for help files

Tags: neovim, folding, save

My current solution to automatically load & save views of a file is the following:

```
" automatically saves & loads folds when closing or opening a file
set viewoptions-=options
augroup remember_folds
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
    autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent! loadview
augroup END
```

The only problem with this is **it is saving views of vim help files** I open (with no folds/edits in the help file). Anyone know how to write something along the lines of:

```
# if file opened is a vim help file:
#    don't save view
# else
#    save view
```

?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think something like this should work: `autocmd BufWinLeave * if &ft !=# 'help' | mkview | endif` and then similarly to restore it `autocmd BufWinEnter * if &ft !=# 'help' | silent! loadview | endif`. Note I used just `*` instead of `*.*` for the pattern... Unless you really don't want to match files that don't have an extension anywhere, which I think is unlikely... Would you mind trying these two above and seeing if they work for you? Thanks!

Comment: I dont have references offhand, but this kind of autocommand does seem to cause lots of trouble when folks forget about it and then they cant get folds/options/whatever to do what they want bc the autocommand keeps restoring old versions. Consider using sessions instead

Comment: @filbranden that seems to do the trick, thanks! The reason I do the `*.*`. instead of of `*` is because using the `*` will save a view of terminal windows. Probably not a huge issues, but I imagine the view directory could get kind of out of hand.

Comment: @Ben I recall seeing issues with this but it was mostly due to restoring options, so `set viewoptions-=options` should take care of that for the most part. Not sure what you mean about sessions, since `:mksession` actually creates a script that will restore views, so isn't that essentially the same? (See step 9 in help of `:mksession`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your `autocmd`s check what the `&filetype` is when making a decision. For something as short as checking that it's different from `'help'` you might be able to go with a one-liner (use `|` to separate commands), for something more complex go with a separate `:function` (to help keep your sanity!)

For your specific case:

```
set viewoptions-=options
augroup remember_folds
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWinLeave *.* if &ft !=# 'help' | mkview | endif
    autocmd BufWinEnter *.* if &ft !=# 'help' | silent! loadview | endif
augroup END
```

You mentioned using `*.*` as a pattern instead of `*` to avoid matching terminal buffers. That's also something you could potentially check inside an `if` statement, for example checking for `&buftype !=# 'terminal'`.